# TKINTER - How to keep the main loop from waiting a validate command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-multithreading

I have an username entry field that validates it's contents by checking if it exists within the domain, the only problem is that this call takes about 1 ~ 2 seconds to return, is there a way to use threading to keep the mainloop from waiting the validate command?

Example code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess
from typing import NoReturn

class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry('300x300')
        self.title('test app')

        self.__CreateWidgets()

    def Start(self) -> None:
        self.mainloop()

    def __CreateWidgets(self) -> None:
        self.__errorlabel = tk.Label(
            self,
            text = '',
            foreground = 'red'
        )
        self.__errorlabel.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

        self.__userIDentry = tk.Entry(
            self,
            validate = 'focusout',
            validatecommand = (self.register(self.__UserIDValidator), '%P'), #This is what I wan't to change.
            invalidcommand = lambda: self.__errorlabel.config(
                text = 'Invalid user ID'
            )
        )
        self.__userIDentry.grid(column = 0, row = 1)
        self.__userIDentry.bind('<FocusIn>', lambda _: self.__errorlabel.config(
                text = ''
            )
        )

        tk.Entry( #This is just a blank entry to click on to test the previous entry validation.
            self,
        ).grid(column = 0, row = 2)

    def __UserIDValidator(self, string:str) -> bool:
        #This function takes about 1 ~ 2 seconds to return:

        flag = False
        if string:
            p = subprocess.Popen(
                f'net user /domain {string}',
                stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr = subprocess.PIPE
            )
            error = p.stderr.read()

            if not error:
                flag = True
        return flag

def main() -> NoReturn:
    app = GUI()
    app.Start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[Running App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bm7OF.png)

You should be able to copy and run the code above if you're on a domain, it basically sends a `net user /domain` command and checks if there was any error on the request, the program freezes until the validation is complete, so is there a way to run the validation and keep the mainloop from getting stuck?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, I fixed it with threading:

```py
import threading

def my_function():
    something_somewhat_intensive()


def my_function_thr():
    thr = threading.Thread(target=my_functioon)
    thr.start()
```

Then you call my_function_thr() to begin that process on a thread. I don't know how this interacts with the import 'subprocess' at all, but this fixed a lot of problems that I had.
It should also be mentioned that if your process is resource intensive, and a bit more than like saving a file or something, use [Multiprocessing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKl2JW_qrso). For a lot of processes, especially with just wanting the Tkinter window to not freeze, I do recommend threading.

Comment: Yes I've been using threading in the project, I'm not sure how I would change the code in the example to thread the validate command.

Comment: So for the function "__UserIDValidator" make a new function:
def __UserIDValidator_thr():
    thr = threading.Thread(target=__UserIDValidator)
    thr.start()
You make a second function, and call the new one.

Comment: Main loop keeps on waiting for a return from `__UserIDValidator_thr()`.

Comment: Do you mean waiting on a return like it freezes and stops responding? Because if it is,  threading will fix that. Im strongly assuming you have something set up incorrectly

Comment: Yes, it just freezes until `validatecommand` has received a boolean, that might be something I'm not setting up correctly because passing arguments and getting return values from threading is not something that I'm very used to do.

Comment: Do you want to create an 'answer' like I did above and I'll see if I can help you there? Its hard to help without seeing code lol. Just posted what you have after you added the threading stuff